# Error when `DISTINCT` keyword is used?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Please have a look at the below query

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
DISTINCT Client.Name AS "Client Name", 
Portfolio.Portfolio_Type 
FROM Client_Portfolio 
INNER JOIN Client ON Client.idClient = Client_Portfolio.idClient 
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Portfolio.idPortfolio = Client_Portfolio.idPortfolio 
WHERE Portfolio.Portfolio_Type = "Out"
```

I wanted to remove the records which duplicates the "Client Name" so I used the keyword `distinct`. But it gives the below error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct (Client.Name) AS "Client Name",
Portfolio.Portfolio_Type
FROM Client_' at line 2
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Put `DISTINCT` after `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `select distinct` is exactly that, `select distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.*, c.Name AS "Client Name", p.Portfolio_Type 
FROM Client_Portfolio cp INNER JOIN
     Client cp
     ON c.idClient = cp.idClient INNER JOIN
     Portfolio
     ON p.idPortfolio = cp.idPortfolio 
WHERE p.Portfolio_Type = 'Out';
```

It applies to *all* columns in the `select` list.

I don't know if this is what you want, but it is the correct syntax.

Note I made two other changes to your query.  First, I added table aliases to make the query easier to write and to read.  Second, I put the string constant in single quotes rather than double quotes.